# In Google Photos, when I try to delete a photo or video on SD card it tells me to go to gallery

Tags: google-photos

I have 2 Mi note 4g's and both of them have the same problem. I have also given access to all permissions in settings(though there is no permission for SD card). All the photos outside the SD card can be deleted all right.

[image: This is the error message]

Answer (score 1):

> Your issue is you haven't allow SD card access from the app itself:

1. Hamburger menu (Three dots) in the upper right.
2. Settings
3. SD Card Access

Regards.

Comment: The problem is as is in Google help it is said this method works for Android 5 up only. My phone is Android 4.4.